# Parse string values

Tags: objective-c, parsing

-  i'm trying to parse this string values with Objective-C.

```
  NSString * str= @"MyDataCallBack({
      "one": "john",
      "two": "mark",
      "three": "hanna"
    });";
```

i want to get the value content by name. Please consider this pseudo code:

NSString * data = parse("one");

**then it will output the value of "one"**

NSLog(@"The data value is %@\n", data); // The data value is john

but i don't have any idea how to achieve that. Please help me to achieve

that and show me how that is done with code.

Comment: Your question is lacking in details, the more detailed your answer is the more likely you are to get a reply from other users. For example you could let us know what you have tried and where you are getting stuck on.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly use the NSJSONSerialization to achieve this:

```
NSString * str= @"MyDataCallBack({\"one\": \"john\", \"two\": \"mark\", \"three\": \"hanna\"});";
str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"MyDataCallBack(" withString:@""];
str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@");" withString:@""];
NSData *data = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *ec = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:nil];
NSLog(@"%@",ec[@"one"]);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: If the strings `"MyDataCallBack("` or `");"` occur other than at the start and end of `str` this code will function incorrectly. You need to remove them only if they are the prefix/suffix respectively.